# Traer desde una coleccion todos aquellos documentos que tienen un campo en especifico con valor duplicado

Tags: mongodb

Estoy buscando poder traerme desde una coleccion todos aquellos documentos que tienen un campo con valor duplicado.

Por ejemplo, teniendo estos registros:

```
{ id: abc100, nombre: "Juan", folio: 001},
{ id: abc101, nombre: "Pedro", folio: 001},
{ id: abc102, nombre: "Diego", folio: 002},
{ id: abc103, nombre: "Jose", folio: 003},
{ id: abc104, nombre: "Felipe", folio: 004},
{ id: abc105, nombre: "Juan", folio: 004},
{ id: abc106, nombre: "Felipe", folio: 005}
```

Lo que busco es poder traerme todos aquellos en el que el numero de folio es el mismo, es decir deberia traerme:

```
{ id: abc100, nombre: "Juan", folio: 001},
{ id: abc101, nombre: "Pedro", folio: 001},
{ id: abc104, nombre: "Felipe", folio: 004},
{ id: abc105, nombre: "Juan", folio: 004}
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda al respecto!

Comment: Y qué has intentado o investigado? O quieres que lo hagamos todo por ti? Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Saludos

Comment: Depronto podrías usar `$group` para hacer un conteo por `folio` y luego los que tengan mas de 2 los consultas de nuevo. O quizás mejor, haciendo un `$lookup` hacia la misma coleccion, que te indique si hay otro elemento en esa coleccion con el mismo `folio` pero con `id` diferente.